# Select Case Statement does not follow integer variable value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

This is an excerpt from my code:

```
Dim x as Integer
x = 0
Select Case x


Case x = 0 'LINE 4
find_Element = fin_Array(x)

    If Trim(find_Element) <> "" Then
        For k = 3 To last_WS
            With Sheets(k).Range("1:200")
                sh_Name = Worksheets(k).Name
                Set pointer_to_Element = .Find(find_Element, _
                    .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, _
                    xlNext, False)
                pointer_Int_Row = CInt(pointer_to_Element.Row)
                'pointer_Int_Col = CInt(pointer_to_Element.Column)

                Worksheets(k).Cells(pointer_Int_Row, lock_Col).Copy
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B8").Offset(, q).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B7").Offset(, q).Value = sh_Name
                q = q + 1
            End With
        Next k
    End If
q = 1

Case x = 1
find_Element = fin_Array(x)

    If Trim(find_Element) <> "" Then
        For k = 3 To last_WS
            With Sheets(k).Range("1:200")
                sh_Name = Worksheets(k).Name
                Set pointer_to_Element = .Find(find_Element, _
                    .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, _
                    xlNext, False)
                pointer_Int_Row = CInt(pointer_to_Element.Row)
                pointer_Int_Col = CInt(pointer_to_Element.Column)

                Worksheets(k).Cells(pointer_Int_Row, pointer_Int_Col).Offset(, 2) _
                .Copy
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B8").Offset(, q).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B7").Offset(, q).Value = sh_Name
                q = q + 1
            End With
        Next k
    End If
q = 1
```

My problem is that i explicitly set `x=0` in my code however `VBA` when it goes to LINE 4 it jumps and executes Case x = 1!!!!

How is this possible when i explicitly set `x=0` in my code?

Comment: You need just `Case 0` not `Case x = 0`.

Comment: Ohhhh lem me try a sec

Comment: X=0 and X=1 are expressions and vba will take the value of expression which is true (or 1) and not the value of x.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! If you have time to put an answer i will mark it as correct when the timer allows me and i will edit this question so it is user-friendly by other users. Again thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx it is meant to look like:

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 0
Select Case x
    Case 0
        'do some stuff
    Case 1
        'do other stuff
End Select
```

Expanding on what PeeKay said:

Doing `x = 0` tests if `x` is equal to `0` which will evaluate to `True` which is equivalent to `1` and similarly `x = 1` will evaluate to `False` (or `0`) because x does not equal `1` so your code ends up looking like:

```
Dim x As Integer
x = 0
Select Case x
    Case 1
        'do some stuff
    Case 0
        'do other stuff
End Select
```

Comment: I will mark this as correct in 8 minutes when the timer allows me. This is the correct answer!

Comment: No. Leave your answer. Yours is the better one as you took the time to find references.

Comment: I would not remove the answer as the reference you gave is of value.

Comment: For completeness, I was trying to do Case `myVar <= 0` but the correct way to do it is: `Case Is <=0`. Also for intervals, the correct syntaxis is: `Case Is >= 1, Is <= 30`

Answer (score 2):

To explain Andy's comment:
`Case X= 0` will always return true when you've explicitly set x=0.

Just use:

```
Select Case X
    Case 0
    ' do stuff
    Case 1
    ' do other stuff
    Case Else
    '...
End Select
```